# Access Denied in file upload to Amazon s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-sdk

I am using aws-sdk for upload file to amazon s3 bucket.
And AccessDenied issue has been occured.
I change my access key id, secret key id, s3 bucket name with others then it works well.
So, there is no problem in code.
I think there is an issue in settings in s3 bucket or s3 bucket name that given in code.
I set the s3 bucket name like `s3.amazonaws.com/[my bucket name]/[folder name]`
And set Access control list and bucket policy to public.
But It doesn't working.
Please help me.

Comment: Try to elaborate more your question so people can help you. Which SDK are you using? If possible update the question with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out my problem.
I change the s3 bucket name like `[my bucket name]/[folder name]`
remove `s3.amazonaws.com`